# How to group data

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping

I have something like this:

```
Column 1       column 2     porcentage
hi              safa            0.1
hi              sfdsdf          0.2
hi              sdfd            0.3
hi              xxxx            ...
hi              uuuu            ...
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
Column 1       column 2        Porcentage
                 safa             0.1
                 sfdsdf           0.2
  hi             sdfd             0.3
                 xxxx             ...
                 uuuu             ...
sub total:                        0.6
```

how can i do that on *iReport*? i added a "report group" but it doesnt do anything... just add a grupo header and footer, but i dont get the result that i expect, i'm totally new with *iReport*.

any help will be welcome.. i prefer using the graphical interface rather than writing the xml stuff..

Comment: You can look at [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups) sample and the [*JasperReports Ultimate Guide*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) is also helpful guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to un-check the **Print Repeated Values** on your `$F{Column 1}` detail field  the only issue with this it it will print "hi" on row one not row 3 like you have in your example.